# My function will not return a value to the local variable in C++

Tags: c++, function, return-value

I created a function to determine the value for `cableBoxFeesTotal`, I then have it return the value to the local variable `cableBoxFeesTotal`. When I try to use the value of `cableBoxFeesTotal` outside of the function, the value is 0.00, not the value that was returned from the function. I have been working on this for days, and cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Please advise me on how to fix this issue. Thanks!

I didn't want to post the entire code..it is homework, but I did add the two sections below.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cctype>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;

    const double BASIC_CABLE = 43.00;
    const double PREMIUM_CABLE = 58.00;
    const double BASIC_BOX = 7.50;
    const double PREMIUM_BOX = 11.25;
    const double PREMIUM_CHANNEL_FEE = 9.99;
    const double EMPLOYEE_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT = .14;

    double feeFunction (int cableBoxes, double serviceLevel, double cableBoxFeesTotal, double BASIC_BOX, double PREMIUM_BOX, char B, char P)

    {    
              if   (cableBoxes > 2 && serviceLevel == 'B')
              {          
                   cableBoxFeesTotal = ((cableBoxes - 2) * BASIC_BOX);
                   cout << "Cable Box Fees:  " << setw(15) << cableBoxFeesTotal << endl;
              }
              else if (cableBoxes > 2 && serviceLevel == 'P')
              {
                   cableBoxFeesTotal = ((cableBoxes - 2) * PREMIUM_BOX);
                   cout << "Cable Box Fees:  " << setw(15) << cableBoxFeesTotal << endl;
              }
              return (cableBoxFeesTotal);
    }

    int main()
    {

        string employee;

        bool hasPremium;

        char H;
        char B;
        char P;
        char premiumChannel;
        char serviceLevel;

        int cableBoxes = 0 ;

        double customerID;
        double monthlyRateTotal = 0.00;
        double cableBoxFeesTotal = 0.00;
        double premiumChannelTotal = 0.00;
        double subtotal = 0.00;`enter code here`
        double employeeDiscount = 0.00;
        double total = 0.00;

        feeFunction (cableBoxes, serviceLevel, cableBoxFeesTotal, BASIC_BOX, PREMIUM_BOX, B, P);
        cout << cableBoxFeesTotal << endl;

         if (hasPremium == true)
         {
              subtotal = (cableBoxFeesTotal + monthlyRateTotal + PREMIUM_CHANNEL_FEE);
              cout << "Subtotal:" << setw(15) << subtotal << endl;
         }
         else if (hasPremium == false)
         {
               subtotal = (monthlyRateTotal + cableBoxFeesTotal);
               cout << "Subtotal:" << setw(15) << subtotal << endl;
         }
   }
```

Comment: Your code snippet seems broken...

Comment: Apparently, You're missing a function call to `feeFunction` in your code.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: I've formatted your code, please review it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually call the function anywhere, so it's unclear what you think is supposed to happen. Furthermore, note that the parameter `cableBoxFeesTotal` in the method and the local variable `cableBoxFeesTotal` in `main()` are two separate unrelated variables. You need to do something like this in `main()`:

```
cableBoxFeesTotal = feeFunction (1, 1.0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 'b', 'p');
```

to call it (where I've just made up values for the parameters, since I don't know what you intend.) Looking over the code, I see that the names of most of the parameters to the function duplicate the names of global or local variables elsewhere; I suspect you just don't really know how parameters work yet, is that right? IN which case, you need to go back to your textbook and do some more reading.

Comment: This is my second user function I have done. The instructor had us do it this way, I will look up a different way to do them now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

could you show me codes for the `int main()` and in this code, I dont see where you use the function feeFunction(). If I still remember, to return a value, we just use `return cableBoxFeesTotal;` .  Let me re-check the C++ syntax first and I'll come back with a more concrete answer to solve this. In meanwhile, please dump full codes for this one.

First your function usage is wrong.  When you return a value through function, when call - you need to put the value in variable.

make it as:

```
double totalFeeFunction = feeFunction (cableBoxes, serviceLevel, cableBoxFeesTotal, BASIC_BOX, PREMIUM_BOX, B, P);
```

Only then you could use it with the value return to your main is in `totalFeeFunction`

Comment: I posted the section where I call the function, and the code after it where I need the value from the function, to calculate subtotal.

Answer (score 0):

if you were to call your function `feeFunction` with the parameters you defined in main `cableBoxes` is ALWAYS < 2. Since the computation part of your function checks to see that `cableBoxes > 2` it ALWAYS skips the computations and returns the value originally assigned to `cableBoxFeesTotal` namely `0.00`

Furthermore, you define your globals as const, so even if the computations were happening in the function, it wouldn't change the global values you defined.

It is still unclear what you are trying to compute etc... but with some more information I can try to advise you on what to do to fix your code. For now suffice it to say make sure your conditions in the function are checking things appropriately.

Comment: cableBoxes is set later by user input, so it will be at least 2. I don't need the global values to change, just the local variable cableBoxFeesTotal. After the function is called, I need the value to be stored in the local variable, to use in the next section of code, to determine the subtotal. I just can't get it to store the value in the local variable.

Comment: @Namawen, you should make sure that fact is reflected in the code that you post. As for the solution, you are not using the assignment operator `=` to assign the value returned from the function to any variables in main.